# Fetch Type LAZY still causes Eager loading Hibernate Spring data

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have created a simple Spring boot project with Spring data.

I have a TagGroup Entity which has one to many relation with Tags.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "TAG_GROUP")
 public class TagGroup{

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "tagGroup")
  private Set<Tag> tagList;

 }
```

The Tag Entity is as below

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "TAGS")
  public class Tag {

      @ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_GROUP_ID")
       private TagGroup tagGroup;

  }
```

I am using Spring data extending the JPArepository and using its findAll method.

The problem , the Lazy fetch doesn't work BUT Infact it is loading the tag list also without calling the tagList explicitly as If it is EAGER...

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you show the method/class where you are retrieving this object and expecting the LazyInitialization exception.

Comment: Its not that I am expecting the lazy Initialization exception. Its just that the behaviour is eager when it should be lazy . I am using standard MVC stucture . The Spring data interface is autowired to service which is being called by Controller. Besides as I said this is Basic Spring boot project and nothing more here.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of property `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`.

As per the [spring-boot-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) Spring boot applications use `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`.

With this property it

> Register OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor. Binds a JPA EntityManager to the thread for the entire processing of the request.

So in your case, subsequently when you call the `getTagList()` i.e., retrieve the `tagList`, it subsequently fires another query to fetch the `tagList` as the the `EntityManager` is still open.

As you might know, `LazyInitializationException` is never thrown if the `entityManager` that has loaded the parent is still open.

To override this, you can add `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in your `application.properties/application.yml` and then you should see `LazyInitializationException`.

Comment: Sorry Madhusudana ,  spring.jpa.open-in-view=true is to keep the same EntityManager for current web request to avoid lazy initialization exception   which I am not getting anyways !!! So, please forget that part. Perhaps You misread the question, I have rephrased my question. Please re read it.

Comment: @DragonZoned I think I got it. So you are **not calling the tagList explicitly** still the tagList entities. That is interesting. Can you please post the sql queries that is getting fired when the call to `findAll` happens.

Comment: @DragonZoned As per the mapping it should be lazy. I suspect, may be the tagList is getting called implicitly or `toString()` of `TagGroup`. To rule out that possibility, since, I think you must be calling the `findAll()` method from some `service` class, can you put a `System.out.println("Loaded Taggroup")` immediately after that line, where you are calling `findAll()` method. If we see any `select` query being fired to fetch the taglist after that the above `sysout` we can atleast be sure that the loading of tagList is not EAGER and bcos of some implicit call that is happening later.

Comment: Got the problem. The problem is the serialization when I send the list as response from controller. The model bean is calling the tag list during serialization which is causing the problem. Either I will need a way to avoid hibernate calling the taglist when serializating or Use a view object to populate the model bean properties and send it to response.

Comment: @DragonZoned That's cool. Is it a JSOn serialization, if so you may want to consider using `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: With JsonIgnore I wont be able to access TagList  in UI no matter what . kinda pointless to put the taglist in the bean in the first place ...

Comment: use `@JsonView` to determine when to serialize and when not to

Comment: Madhusudana Reddy , thank you, it worked for me. Just like most hibernate related problems, the answer from StackOverflow  works for one out of 15 people.. So i am not surprised from reading the comments.